# Asp.Net MVC LINQ query to check if agreement already exists between 2 dates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Asp.Net MVC5 project which I need some help with. The Logic is that a Customer needs to have an agreement. This is fine because I can create the first agreement. The problem I am having is that if another agreement needs to be created for the customer it can't be within the same period as the existing one. Initially I am thinking of placing something into the Agreement controller in the Create method to do the check. 
What I have currently is

Controller:

```
 // GET: Agreements/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int? Id, string Name)
    {

        if (Id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Agreement model = new Agreement();
       // model.FullName = Name;
        model.CustomerId = Id;

        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name");
        ViewBag.SupplierId = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierId", "Name");

        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: Agreements/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AgreementId,CustomerId,CustomerHasAgreement,SupplierId,Start,End,AgreementPlanId,AgreementType")] Agreement agreement)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var bExist = db.Agreements.Any(s => (s.Start <= agreement.End && s.End >= agreement.Start));    //or your check logic
            if (!bExist)
            { 
                db.Agreements.Add(agreement);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Agreements", new { id = agreement.AgreementId });
            }
            else 
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Sorry something happened unexpectedly !!!");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name", agreement.CustomerId);
        ViewBag.SupplierId = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierId", "Name", agreement.SupplierId);
        return View(agreement);
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class Agreement
{
    public int AgreementId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public bool CustomerHasAgreement { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
    public int? AgreementPlanId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public virtual Plan Plans { get; set; }
    public int weeks { get; set; }

    public AgreementType AgreementType { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

 }

public enum AgreementType
{
    Low = 1,
    Moderate = 2,
    High = 3,
    Emergency = 4,
    Temporary = 5,
    [Display(Name = "Long Term")]
    Long_Term = 6
}    
}
```

I have tried to use a LINQ statement to check to see if the new agreement is greater than the end date of the old agreement.

```
 var bExist = db.Agreements.Any(s => (s.Start <= agreement.End && s.End >= agreement.Start));    //or your check logic
```

This only seems to either skip over the if statement and not insert the record

Please can someone help me please. I have tried going through the Microsoft tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application
but seem to constantly get stuck when trying to implement it into my solution.

Many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@markabarmi Do an OR operator. You're looking for 1 or 2 of 2 possible issues. Doesn't need to have both to trigger bExists to be true. Also limit that result set to your specific customer in question.

```
var bExist = db.Agreements.Any(s => (s.CustomerId == agreement.CustomerId) && ((s.Start <= agreement.End) || (s.End >= agreement.Start)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mwwallace8, I have tried that but it still skips it and jumps straight into my `else` statement, even though a customer doesn't even have an agreement.

Comment: @markabarmi ... you know what. You probably need to add the argument to make sure you're looking at the correct customer. I've added that to the lambda to reflect what I mean. Without the customerId limiting the result set you're getting unrelated records returned.

Comment: Thanks @mwwallace8 , your right needed to add the argument in for the customer. Used your answer and it seems to be working :) Thank you